# Validating input field using regEx not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I was asked to validate our input fields. In that way I limited the characters you'll be able to fill in in an input field. My input field will increment whenever I add some data and I'm using one id for all.

It works on the first row but the rest it doesn't. Any suggestions how to fix it?

```
            echo""
            . "<form action=maintenance.php method=POST>"
            . "<tr>"
            . "<td><input class='textbox' type=text id='name' name=name value='" . $record['name'] . "'> </td>"
            . "<td><input class='textbox' size=50 id='url' type=url name=url value='" . $record['url'] . "'></td>"
            . "<td><textarea class=textbox rows=2 cols=50 wrap=physical id=desc name=desc>" . strip_tags($record['description']) . "</textarea></td>"
            . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value='" . $record['name'] . "'>"
            . "<td><button class='btn-style-icons shrink' type=submit name=update><img src=icons/update.png alt=Update></button></td>"
            . "<td><button class='btn-style-icons shrink' type=submit name=delete><img src=icons/delete.png alt=Delete></button></td>"
            . "</tr>"
            . "</form>";
        }
        echo""
        . "</table>"
        . "<table>"
        . "<form action=maintenance.php method=POST>"
        . "<tr>"
        . "<td><input class='textbox' id='name' type=text name=iname></td>"
        . "<td><input class='textbox' id='url' size= 50 url=url name=iurl></td>"
        . "<td><textarea class=textbox id=desc rows=2 cols=50 name=idesc></textarea></td>"
        . "<td><button class='btn-style-icons shrink' type=submit name=add id=add><img src=icons/add.png alt=Add></button></td>"
        . "</tr>"
        . "</form>"
        . "</table>";
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

**action.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#name').bind('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 \b\t]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('#url').bind('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9://. \b\t]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ID need to be unique, use classes instead. If for some reason you want invalid code, just add a space at the start of your select : `$(' #name')`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon OMG YOU'RE A LIFE SAVER. PLEASE answer, so i can accept it :D

Comment: Use native regex syntax: `var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9 \b\t]+$/;` - your regular expression won't work as it is because you didn't escape the backslashes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Good solution

ID must be unique, so instead of `id="name"` or `id="url"`, use `class="name"` and `class="url"`. Afterward, you can change your selector to `.name` and `.url` and it will work.

## Hack solution

If for some reason you want invalide HTML and duplicate your IDs, you can exploit jQuery and insert a space before the selector. It will return more than 1 element.

```
$(' #name')
$(' #url')
```

#### Do not use that except if you have a gun against your head and someone ask you to debug his code without changing the HTML. Use classes, that's why they exist.

Comment: thanks :) Class didn't work for me. So i needed the hack solution :)

Answer (score 1):

HTML ids must be unique per page.  If you want to select multiple elements by the same identifier, you should use a class.  Remember that each html element can have multiple classes.  So for your example you may want to have a class attribute that looks something like `class='textbox name'`.  Then you can select everything with the name class using jquery `$(.name)`.

You can find more info about class vs id here: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Also, if you're just trying to limit the number of characters in an input, the javascript solution may be overkill for you as you can just set a `maxlength` property on the input.